# Prove that for each $x \in \mathbb R$ there is a choice of signs $s_{n}=\{-1,1\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{s_{n}}{\sqrt n}$ converges to x.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that for each $x \in \mathbb R$ there is a choice of signs $s_{n}=\{-1,1\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{s_{n}}{\sqrt n}$ converges to x.

Can anyone suggest some hint for this question?

Comment: My guess is that you consider the partial sums. If $ \sum_{n=1}^i \frac{s_n}{\sqrt{n}} < x$ then set $s_{i+1} = 1$, else set it to $-1$. As for proving this converges to x, I have no clue.

Comment: Help us understand what you already know.  What have you tried?  What is the context of this question?  Do you know that the terms of a conditionally convergent series can always be rearranged to get any sum you want?  This question is a specific example of that more general proposition.

Comment: @jonan  It's not hard to prove that the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy, which gets you convergence, and it's relatively easy to prove that if the sequence of partial sums for the series as you've defined it converges at all, it must converge to $x$.  And as a technical matter, you also need to define $s_{i+1}$ if the partial sum equals $x$.

Comment: @Robet Shore, firstly I tried to prove the partial sum is Cauchy. i.e $|u_{n}-u_{m}|=|\sum_{i=m+1}^{n} \frac{s_{i}}{\sqrt{i}}|\leq |\frac{1}{\sqrt(m+1)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt(m+2)}+.........+\frac{1}{\sqrt(n)}|$

Comment: I'd go with the strategy to show that after reaching the close enough neighbourhood of $x$ with the initial part of the series, we can always stay within an interval of length $cn^{-1/2}$ centered at $x$ after the $n$th step (at first glance $c=4$ should work), which gives you the convergence. By symmetry assume $x>0$ and let  $M$ satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^M i^{-1/2}\geq x> \sum_{i=1}^{M-1} i^{-1/2}$, so when you exceed $x$, you'll be within this $cn^{-1/2}$ interval, and not stepping out via jonan's strategy is straightforward.